# Yii - Remove 'index' from URL

Tags: php, url, seo, yii

How do I remove `index` from `http://localhost/dashboard/index/create`

I have my `urlManager` setup like this:

```
'urlManager' => array(
     'urlFormat' => 'path',
     'showScriptName' => false,
     'rules' => array(
         '<controller:\w+>/<id:\d+>' => '<controller>/view',
         '<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>/<id:\d+>' => '<controller>/<action>',
         '<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>' => '<controller>/<action>',
     ),
 ),
```

And this gives me clean URLs like this `http://localhost/dashboard` where `dashboard` is a module with a default controller named `indexController`.

Now, the problem I am having is that I cannot access other actions of the module controller without first putting `index` e.g If I want to call `actionCreate` inside `indexController`, I always have to say `http://localhost/dashboard/index/create`.

Is there any way I can get rid of `index` and just call it like this: `http://localhost/dashboard/create`?

This is how my module is configured in `main.php` :

```
'modules' => array(
    ...
    'dashboard' => array(
        'defaultController' => 'index'
    ),
    ...
),
```

Thank you in advance :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try arranging your array like this (put the line beginning with dashboard under your urlManager component):

```
array(
  ...
  'components' => array(
    ...
    'urlManager' => array(
      ...
        'rules' => array(
          'dashboard/<action:\w+>' => 'dashboard/index/<action>'
      ),
    ),
  ),
);
```

Comment: This solves my problem, but now I keep encountering errors such as: `Error 404 : Can't find the action 'dashboard/dashboard/create'`. Is this a side effect? I call my actions like this `http://localhost/dashboard/create`, but I don't know how I end up with 2 `dashboard` on the URL. Any ideas before I close this thread?

Comment: Hmm I don't see why there's an extra dashboard being added. Does .htaccess do anything?

Comment: This is all I have in my .htaccess:

`RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . index.php`

Comment: Maybe there's another component that's prefixing any call with the default module or something. You'll have to check the config.php file. Also your error message doesn't have the word `index` in it, so it appears as if it's never even reaching this rule.

Comment: After further investigation, it appears it's the relative addresses I was using in ajax. Sorry about that, and thank you :-)

Comment: This answer is helpful but it should be noticed that there is `'urlManager' => ... 'rules' => array('dashboard/...')` structure actually.

Comment: @Kremchik - you are right; I just edited the answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can create `.htaccess file` for that:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /project_folder_NAME
# if a directory or a file exists, use it directly
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

# otherwise forward it to index.php
RewriteRule . index.php
```