# How to rewrite a URL in Yii framework?

Tags: php, url, yii

How can I rewrite a URL if I have the following path:

```
http://localhost/site/index.php/site/scoreBoard/id/sherxon.obidov
```

and I want it to be:

```
http://localhost/site/index.php/scoreBoard/sherxon.obidov
```

I have tried the following :

```
'<action:(contact|login|logout|index|scoreBoard|register|solved|error|activate)>/<id:\w+>'
     =>  'site/<action>/<\w+>'
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Yii - Remove 'index' from URL](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11530174/yii-remove-index-from-url)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) The regex `<id:\w+>` only allows a word character, which is from a-z, A-Z, 0-9, including the _ (underscore) character. Your full-stop will not work.

Change `<id:\w+>` to `<id>`.

2) `'site/<action>/<\w+>'` is also wrong, change to `'site/<action>/<id>'`